# Nested struct inside constexpr function, compiles in clang, fails in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, constexpr, clang++

Im having trouble with the following code, I am trying to write a compile time square root function. The code compiles on the most recent clang 6.0.
yet fails on the most recent version of gcc 8.0. the issue seems to be with the initialisation of the struct.

GCC output

```
 error: uninitialized variable 'sqrtNewtonRaphson' in 'constexpr' context
     } sqrtNewtonRaphson;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The last version of gcc that this code compiles on is gcc 6.3, in the following versions after that, compile_time_sqrt_ver1(double) fails to compile.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr double
compile_time_sqrt_ver1(double x) {
    struct {
        constexpr double operator() (double x, double current, double previous) {
            return current == previous ? current : (*this)(x, 0.5 * (current + x / current), current);
        }
    } sqrtNewtonRaphson; 

    return x >= 0 && x < std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
           ? sqrtNewtonRaphson(x, x, 0)
           : std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    constexpr double test_v1 = compile_time_sqrt_ver1(24);
    return test_v1;
}
```

The solution I found to this is to add {} at the end of the struct making it compile in the most recent version of gcc as well as clang. why is this?

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr double
compile_time_sqrt_ver2(double x) {
    struct {
        constexpr double operator() (double x, double current, double previous) {
            return current == previous ? current : (*this)(x, 0.5 * (current + x / current), current);
        }
    } sqrtNewtonRaphson{}; // <- change {}

    return x >= 0 && x < std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
           ? sqrtNewtonRaphson(x, x, 0)
           : std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    constexpr double test_v2 = compile_time_sqrt_ver2(24);
    return test_v2;
}
```

Comment: live demo https://godbolt.org/g/xw8rcr

Comment: Btw, why do you need a nested struct here?

Comment: @erenon because I don’t need to call the function anywhere else. And recursive lambdas aren’t a thing

Comment: For some reason the default constexpr constructor is not created. The same issue happens if you use a named classes  instead of an anonymous struct and then declare a variable of that type. I guess that {} forces the compiler to generate the default constructor and call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is right; Clang is wrong.

Per [basic.types] your anonymous struct is an aggregate type (and therefore a literal type), so it should be constexpr constructible. (N4659 §6.9/10)

However, you are not initializing your aggregate. Aggregates are not default constructed upon declaration. This is why adding the braces `{}` afterwards enables it to work (aggregate initialization)

A `constexpr` function requires that all variables be initialized per [dcl.constexpr] §10.1.5/3.4.5 (**emphasis mine**)

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements: 
> [...]
>  — its *function-body* shall be `= delete`, `= default`, or a compound-statement that does not contain 
>       — a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration **or for which no
>   initialization is performed**.

If you add a `constexpr` constructor, then it will also work (the type remains literal but is no longer aggregate, so you are not required to explicitly initialize it). However, this would also require you to name your struct.

Comment: Thank you! There’s no way I would have figured that out. would you suggest reporting this to clang ?

Comment: @DanielCollier: I would. I've admittedly never submitted a bug report to them (despite encountering plenty over time), so I'm unfamiliar with the process.

Answer (score 1):

Just move it out as another function:

```
constexpr double sqrtNewtonRaphson (double x, double current, double previous) {
            return current == previous ? current : sqrtNewtonRaphson(x, 0.5 * (current + x / current), current);
        }
constexpr double compile_time_sqrt_ver2(double x) {
    return x >= 0 && x < std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
           ? sqrtNewtonRaphson(x, x, 0)
           : std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    constexpr double test_v2 = compile_time_sqrt_ver2(24);
    return test_v2;
}
```

---

EDIT made method static

```
constexpr double compile_time_sqrt_ver2(double x) {
    struct SNR{
        static constexpr double sqrtNewtonRaphson (double x, double current, double previous) {
            return current == previous ? current : sqrtNewtonRaphson(x, 0.5 * (current + x / current), current);
        }
    }; 

    return x >= 0 && x < std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
           ? SNR::sqrtNewtonRaphson(x, x, 0)
           : std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}
```

Comment: I am aware that I can do this, but i want to know what the issue is whith Gcc not accepting it but clang does. I also don’t want to make another function as it will not be used anything else other than the compile_time_sqrt function. Using a lambs would be great but I don’t think it’s possible

Comment: Lamba* I’m not an animal

Comment: If you want to keep it in the struct you don't actually need an instance. see edit